ValueObject/Entity Used in multiple other entities
I can't figure out how to configure ef core to handle an ValueObject that needs to be persisted and used in multiple entities. I am trying to adhere to DDD. I have a ValueObject called GradingPeriod. Its a ValueObject because its determined by the Date Range and the Organization. However I can't figure out how to persist it to the DB and also use it in multiple other entities that need to use it. Currently I have it ownedby the organization as they will be the controller of when grading periods begin and end. I need to be able to use it in things like a IEP for start and end grading periods and also in Goals or Objectives that have a grading period assigned to them.
Here is a snipped from organization and its config:
public class Organization: BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    private readonly List<GradingPeriod> _gradingPeriods = new();
    public IEnumerable<GradingPeriod> GradingPeriods => _gradingPeriods.AsReadOnly();
    
    private Organization() { } // For EF
    
    public Organization(Guid id, string name, string description)
    {
        Id = Guard.Against.Default(id);
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(name);
        Description = description;
    }
}

Config
builder.OwnsMany<GradingPeriod>(x => x.GradingPeriods, gradingPeriod =>
        {
            gradingPeriod.ToTable("organization_grading_period");
            gradingPeriod.Property<int>("Id").HasColumnName("id");
            gradingPeriod.HasKey("Id");
            gradingPeriod.Property(x => x.OrganizationId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("organization_id");
            gradingPeriod.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("name");
            gradingPeriod.OwnsOne(t => t.LocalDateRange, childBuilder =>
            {
                childBuilder.Property(x => x.Start).HasColumnName("date_start");
                childBuilder.Property(x => x.End).HasColumnName("date_end");
            });
        });

This is GradingPeriod
public class GradingPeriod : ValueObject
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public LocalDateRange LocalDateRange { get; private set; }
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; private set; }
    
    // For EF
    private GradingPeriod() { }
    
    public GradingPeriod(string name, LocalDateRange localDateRange, Guid organizationId)
    {
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(name);
        LocalDateRange = Guard.Against.Null(localDateRange);
        OrganizationId = Guard.Against.Default(organizationId);
    }
    
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Name;
        yield return LocalDateRange;
        yield return OrganizationId;
    }
}

Here is a snip from IEP Objective and part of its config as you can see from the commented code I have been trying different things but getting different errors:
public class Objective: BaseEntity<Guid>, ITimestamped
{
    public Guid GoalId { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public GradingPeriod GradingPeriodStart { get; private set; }
    public GradingPeriod GradingPeriodDue { get; private set; }
    public PromptType PromptType { get; private set; }
    public int? MaxPrompts { get; private set; }
    public Percentage AccuracyGoal { get; private set; }
    public int TrialsPerGradingPeriod { get; private set; }
    public int SuccessfulTrialsGoal { get; private set; }
    public Instant CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Instant? LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
    
    private readonly List<Trial> _trials = new();
    public IEnumerable<Trial> Trials => _trials.AsReadOnly();
    
    private Objective() { } // For EF
    
    public Objective(Guid id, Guid goalId, string description, GradingPeriod gradingPeriodStart, GradingPeriod gradingPeriodDue, PromptType promptType, int? maxPrompts, Percentage accuracyGoal, int trialsPerGradingPeriod, int successfulTrialsGoal)
    {
        Id = Guard.Against.Default(id);
        GoalId = Guard.Against.Default(goalId);
        Description = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(description);
        GradingPeriodStart = Guard.Against.Null(gradingPeriodStart);
        GradingPeriodDue = Guard.Against.Null(gradingPeriodDue); //TODO: add guard clause for due date after start date
        PromptType = Guard.Against.Null(promptType);
        MaxPrompts = Guard.Against.Zero(Guard.Against.Null(maxPrompts));
        AccuracyGoal = Guard.Against.Null(accuracyGoal);
        TrialsPerGradingPeriod = Guard.Against.Zero(trialsPerGradingPeriod);
        SuccessfulTrialsGoal = Guard.Against.Zero(successfulTrialsGoal);
    }
}

Config:
goal.OwnsMany(x => x.Objectives, objective =>
            {
                objective.ToTable("iep_objectives");
                objective.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
                goal.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                objective.Property(x => x.GoalId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("goal_id");
                objective.Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(2000).HasColumnName("description");
                // objective.Property(x => x.GradingPeriodStart).HasColumnName("grading_period_start");
                objective.OwnsOne(x => x.GradingPeriodStart);
                objective.OwnsOne(x => x.GradingPeriodDue);
                // objective.HasOne(x => x.GradingPeriodDue).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey<GradingPeriod>(x => new {
                //     x.OrganizationId, x.Name
                // });
                // objective.Property(x => x.GradingPeriodDue).HasColumnName("grading_period_due");

